# How to change font for a particular section?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

Let us consider the following scenario.

This is the partial code in the main.tex file and which includes code from other tex files like certificate.tex, abstract.tex etc.,

```
....................
\include{certificate}
\include{abstract}
\include{introduction}
...................
```

Now I want to incorporate separate font size and font style to each one of the above. For example let us say I want certificate to be of font size 12pt with font family Arial, abstract to be of font size 11pt with font family Courier. And finally the abstract should follow font size and font family, which I declare globally for whole document.

Is it possible to change for particular chapters without changing remaining document.

I am expecting some code like this

```
....................
\font{12pt}{Arial}{\include{certificate}}
\font{11pt}{Courier}{\include{abstract}}
\include{introduction}
...................
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not sure, I think its pdflatex. I am writing my code in https://www.overleaf.com/ .

Comment: If it's `pdflatex`, you can't use `Arial` or `Courier` directly, but their `equivalents`: `helvet` for example. I personally wouldn't use too much different fonts in a document

Comment: @ChristianHupfer For me font family is not particular, I wanna know just how to code to change for a particular section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only hints how to change the fonts, although there are other ways, of course. The standard font is `Computer Modern`, to use a font it's necessary to know it's font family and available shapes/series. Important is the `\selectfont` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{m}\fontsize{12}{20}\selectfont % Computer Modern font
\blindtext\par
\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{12}{20}\selectfont   % Helvetica aka. Arial 
\section{Certificate}
\blindtext\par
\begin{abstract}
 \fontfamily{pcr}\fontseries{m} \fontsize{11}{16}\selectfont % Courier font family pcr
  \blindtext\par
\end{abstract}%
\blindtext\par
\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont % Helvetica again

\end{document}
```

**New version**, with *nice* fonts, just to annoy some people here :-P

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setmainfont{orange_juice.ttf}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\section{Certificate}
\fontspec{planetbe.ttf}
\kant[1]
\begin{abstract}
\fontspec{orange_juice.ttf}
\kant
\end{abstract}%
\kant
\end{document}
```

(Fonts downloaded from http://www.1001freefonts.com/comic-cartoon-fonts.php)

Comment: For the Helvetica part the font should be scaled or the baselineskip modified.

Comment: I will update with a `xelatex` version, possibly

Comment: the baselineskip is different befor and after abstract, inserting blank line befor abstract environment fix it

Comment: `\blindtext` doesn't end with `\par`.  i know this is kind of a "duplicate" comment, but i think it's worth saying *why* the baselines are so horrid in the certificate: baselines aren't applied until a paragraph break takes effect.  hence, a blank line or explicit `\par` is needed so that the *intended* value (which is a good one) is actually applied.